# What is the equivalent of Web.config transform in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, publish, configuration-files, appsettings

ASP.NET Core documentation suggests we should use appsettings.json file, along with a file per environment, containing overriding values. The problem is that all these files are published, though only appsettings.json and appsettings.[Environment].json are relevant. 
The other problem is that to change a config value on server one must inspect both files: base and environment specific.

So my question is: what is the cleanest way to have one configuration file in each deployment environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key difference is that ASP.NET Core apps are not deployed for a particular configuration, as ASP.NET apps were. Previously, you'd literally publish as "Release", for example, and if you wanted to switch the deployment config, you'd have to republish. With an ASP.NET Core app, the environment is determined by the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable or by the environment passed during execution. As a result, it's perfectly valid to deploy all possible environmental settings, since the environment can be changed on a whim.

That said, if you know for sure you're never going to change the environment, you can simply remove any `appsettings.{environment}.json` files you don't need. Additionally, you should not really override settings in the man `appsettings.json`. If it's environment-specific, it should go in one of the environment-specific JSON files. Your main `appsettings.json` file should really only contain global settings unaffected by environment. If you handle it in this way, then you don't have to look at both to see where the settings are coming from.

Finally, if you don't like this approach, in general, you can simply choose a different configuration strategy, such as environment variables or an external config source such as Azure Key Vault.

Comment: If I got this correctly, config settings that are environment specific should be externalized. For example, if app is deployed to 5 servers and uses different connection strings, this configuration should be outside appsettings.json. This way there is only one build of the app for all environments.

Comment: Well, yes and no. There's no real "rule" here - just recommendations. You can handle this anyway you want. Yes, it's usually a good idea to externalize environment-specific settings, but with .NET Core, the build is the build is the build. Like I said, there's no "Release" build, "Staging" build, etc. The environment itself is externalized.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Hi, I am working on `.net core 2.1's` API project and I want to publish it on the IIS server, but how do I use profiles for configuration setting for diff. environments?

Answer (score 2):

We can start by looking at the predefined `ConfigurationBuilder` that usually looks something like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

Configuration = builder.Build();
```

You can opt to remove the `AddJosnFile()` if you don't want them in the first place, as sometimes your project may not require this.

If you do intend to use the `appsettings.json` or similar, then it is important to **note the order they are added.** You can see in the code snippet above, that the `appsettings.{env}.json` is added **after**.

This is an important concept to understand, because this means that if there is a file found that matches the filename (for example, `appsettings.Production.json`), **it will replace.override any overlapping configurations.**

Note the use of the words **replace**, **override** and **overlapping**.

You can architect your own tiers and layer your configurations in a suitable way to fit your project. You are not restrained to have on use the `env.EnviornmentName` either, you can use any kind of conditional logic to design it as needed.

If you plan to go this route of customized design. You may want to note that you can reconfigure and alter the configuration as much as you like prior to the `WebHostBuilder` being built (i.e. before the `.Build()` method is called). So, you can be very creative in how you want to programmatically configure your project.