# Equivalent to App.config transforms for .NET Core?

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core

I'm writing a .NET Core console application (***NOT*** an ASP.NET Core web application).  In .NET Framework I would have an `App.config`, and `App.Debug.config`, and an `App.Release.config` file, the latter 2 for transforming the former.  This allowed me to change various settings based on whether I was creating a debug or a release build.

Now with .NET Core, you're meant to use `appsettings.json` instead.  Fine, but how do I do my debug and release transforms with this?  I've read something about using an environment variable to determine whether you're in a release or debug environment but I really don't want to do this and it's not really appropriate for console applications anyway.  So how can I transform config files in a similar way to how it was done in .NET Framework?

Comment: https://lukemerrett.com/environment-specific-configuration-in-dotnet-core/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of Web.config transform in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891794/what-is-the-equivalent-of-web-config-transform-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: I remember there being ways to manage the debug and release config in the .csproj file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer that I found to this is: use [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms).  It implements XDT transformations for .NET Core and in addition allows JSON transformations too with JDT.

Comment: here is a demo https://github.com/d668/NetCoreConfigTransform/ .NET Core 2.2 Console app App.config transforms using slow-cheetah